# What's the meaning of おまっとさんどす?

Tags: meaning

I've found this in a comic frame, but i can't find it's meaning
おまっとさんどす
Maybe おまっと be a kind of お前, but I don't know.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「おまっとさんどす」

is a **Kyoto** way of saying the standard (dictionary):

> 「お待{ま}ちどうさまです」

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8A%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%95%E3%81%BE

which means:

> "***Sorry to have kept you waiting***."

「どす」 is a very "famous" Kyoto version of 「です」.

> 「Honorific お/ご + Noun + Honorific さま/さん」

is a pattern used in very common fixed expressions.  Other examples include:

「お疲{つか}れさま/さんです。」 (Thank you for your hard work.)

「ご苦労{くろう}さま/さん！」 (Thank you for your hard work!)

「ごちそうさま（でした）。」 ("Thank you for the meal.") ➡ 「ごっそさん」 in colloquial speech.

「お気{き}の毒{どく}さまです/でございます。」 ("That is too bad.", "My sympathies.", "My condolences.", etc.)

「お世話{せわ}さまです。」 ("Thank you for your kindness.", "Thank you for everything.", "Thank you for taking care of ~~.", etc.)